# Mount encrypted partition of an image file

Tags: luks, cryptsetup

I've an image backup file of my harddisk, which consists of three partitions (`sudo fdisk -l /mnt/hdd/19_02.img`):

```bsh
Device                 Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/mnt/hdd/19_02.img1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/mnt/hdd/19_02.img2  1050624  34686975  33636352    16G Linux swap
/mnt/hdd/19_02.img3 34686976 976773134 942086159 449.2G Linux filesystem
```

The third partition ist of type `crypto_LUKS`. If it wouldn't be encrypted I could mount it with `sudo mount -o loop,offset=$(expr 512 \* 34686976) /mnt/hdd/19_02.img /mnt/img`, which results in `mount: /mnt/img: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'.`

#### What I've tried

`sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /mnt/hdd/19_02.img3 img` results in `Device /mnt/hdd/19_02.img3 doesn't exist or access denied.`

`sudo cryptsetup plainOpen --offset=$(expr 512 \* 34686976) /mnt/hdd/19_02.img img` asks for my passphrase which also gets accepted, but returns with `Requested offset is beyond real size of device /mnt/hdd/19_02.img.`
Alright, maybe `cryptsetup` does multiply the offset value with the block size by itself.

`sudo cryptsetup plainOpen --offset=34686976 /mnt/hdd/19_02.img img` asks for my passphrase which also gets accepted and returns fine. But `sudo mount /dev/mapper/img /mnt/img` complains `mount: /mnt/img: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/img`. Analysing with `sudo lsblk -f /dev/mapper/img` shows there is no filesystem recognized.

```bsh
NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
img
```

The encrypted device was created by `LUKS` mode, so it properly makes not much sense opening it with `plainOpen`. But `luksOpen` doesn't offer an `--offset` option.

Doing `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen --offset=34686976 /mnt/hdd/19_02.img img` results in `cryptsetup: Option --offset is supported only for open of plain and loopaes devices and for luksFormat`. (Didn't tried `luksFormat`, but it sets up the LUKS device header and encrypts the master-key.)

#### The question after all

How to do `cryptsetup luksOpen` with offset on an image file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`fdisk` is being a bit stupid here: when displaying device names for the partitions, it just takes the name of the whole-disk device given to it, and appends the partition number (prefixed with `p` if the last character of the whole-disk device name is also a number). It does this without checking if a device by that name actually exists or not.

In other words, if your image file is named `/mnt/hdd/19_02.img` and you're using `fdisk` to examine it directly, then partition names like `/mnt/hdd/19_02.img3` are completely fictional and unusable.

Instead of trying to calculate offsets manually, you could simply attach the image file into a loop device and have it automatically detect the partitions for you:

```
sudo losetup -P /dev/loop0 /mnt/hdd/19_02.img
```

If your system is new enough to support the `-P` option for `losetup`, you should now have partition devices like `/dev/loop0p1`, `/dev/loop0p2` and `/dev/loop0p3` appearing automatically.

For older distributions with no partitioned loop device support, you can use the `kpartx` command (may come with the `device-mapper-multipath` tools if not packaged separately) for the same purpose. In that case, you'll have to perform two steps and the device names will be slightly different:

```
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 /mnt/hdd/19_02.img
sudo kpartx -a /dev/loop0
```

When using `kpartx` like this, the partition devices will appear under `/dev/mapper`, e.g. `/dev/mapper/loop0p1` and so on.

Now you should be able to do either

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop0p3 img
```

or

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/mapper/loop0p3 img
```

depending on whether you used `losetup -P` or `kpartx` to handle the partition devices.

---

After you're done accessing the image, unmount any mounted filesystems on the partition devices, `sudo cryptsetup luksClose` the encrypted image, then undo the loop device binding:

If you used `kpartx`, first run `sudo kpartx -d /dev/loop0` to release the partition devices. If you used `losetup -P`, this step is not needed.

Then, release the loop device: `sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked at once :)! And special thanks to consider the possibility of having `losetup -P` or `kpartx` and explaining the difference.

Comment: The `-f` option to `losetup` can be used instead of a loop device, to find and use the first unused loop device rather than supplying one that may already be in use, as documented on https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/losetup.8.html